# How to get a value from <input type="hidden" in Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Hi everyone as summarized in the title I want to get values from an input type="hidden" but it returns 'None'. Does it exist a method to get it?
Thanks in advance!
What I expect is to get values from "PaReq" and "MD"

```
<input type="hidden" name="PaReq" value="eNpVUstuwjAQ/JWID4gfOA+jxRJtKpVKpAjooUfXOJCKJOAkJfx97RCgtXzYmd0dr2YNm73ROllr1RotYKHrWu60l2+nowmLWRBRHhJG4yAidCRgOVvpk4Afbeq8KgXxsU8B3aBtN2ovy0aAVKeneSoCGgZhBGiAUGgzTwYWY0oDjiMM6EpDKQst1gdZeG+yANRDUFVbNuYixrEtvAFozUHsm+ZYTxA6n89+bbu+ZeGryja6JKDHMMvWRbUV6/KtSJMdTjfq8r757NJkzmzcLXYzd6aAXAVsZaMFxYQTggOPjCfM3hhQz4Ms3BTi5WPlcexjO9bAwNE9NLsCjl3mLwPWY6NLdRE8smJ3BLo7VqW2FdbLewzoMfbzq3NUNdakLxKTmI2zSEYqzDgPGY/DQGZZKDPnc1/kFHNrE2U46iUdAORk0LBCNKzaRv++wC/NTqrF">
<input type="hidden" name="MD" value="djRZa0UxelQrcVc5Z0FySWJxdlg0Zz09IVoFvEENTvjwOCe_O4c2oKjmkJX--9pXJipeKnSw3qmylmi9CRNpM_VB7PE6ThiwlR89Siu7qEpUkj7rdnVJLLuXGbViF6O9akJ4lnNqj_kWEveLghKDyAxonmcKg4hSia1VyORwlDlWJ3g9wWjU0bwVvzohyEeTzagDF3f8ggFYIYWgHiJ8ceDr0XSwoFYYxOmlb09yuyCP6LBZd-k3ED8KUo7B5pomsQF3M4RFBtS_dQdBw9wGy9R1cACkzAL0w7BvwNqw5vm3xOyFL7HUGlFbhDOPpFJ8LhEsDQwr2zptI4VBhDt0rYmJkt2hAlzU2OTPGyuvXD-8zWBGI5jcwlqCcCXPlsjMzKCSnfJuFGpxkAFIkqdEGBBKJL7Lqag06OKTO7x2HQaNYmBTKVz1uYG9FE3DUl06MjH7LzBlU1mj7-Bx_YTTuA">
```

This is my code:

```
script = s.get('https://www.slamjam.com/on/demandware.store/Sites-slamjam-Site/en_IT/Adyen-Adyen3D',headers=headers)
bs_3d = BeautifulSoup(script_3d.text,"html.parser")
hidden_tags = bs_3d.find_all("input", type="hidden")
for tag in hidden_tags:
       print(tag.value)
```

Comment: You're specifying `name="PaReq"`, should this be `"PaRequest"`?

Comment: @psilocybin edited sorry! I want to get values of "PaReq" and "MD"

Answer (score 0):

you should use `tag["value"]` instead of `tag.value`.
from [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/index.html?highlight=tag#attributes)

> ## Attributes
>
> A tag may have any number of attributes. The tag `<b id="boldest">` has an attribute “id” whose value is “boldest”. You can access a tag’s attributes by treating the tag like a dictionary:
>
> ```
> >>>tag['id']
> u'boldest'
> ```